# Is it possible to change the behavior of the search bar on modern communication pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, communication-site

I created a new Office 365 SharePoint Communication Site.  Near the top right corner there is a search bar.  Using this search bar redirects me to https://(mysite)/_layouts/15/search.aspx/siteall?q=(query)

I would like it to not do this.

I have tried changing the settings here /_layouts/15/enhancedSearch.aspx?level=site
and here /_layouts/15/enhancedSearch.aspx?level=sitecol
 and waited the 30 minutes it specifies and, while it does change the behavior of the search box on those page, it does not affect the communication pages.

Has anyone had any success changing the behavior of this box, or do I just make a new search box and stick it somewhere else on the page?  Is this a Microsoft bug?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you cannot change the default behavior of the search box on Modern Pages. There are no "settings" to control. You also cannot (currently) change the rendering, filtering, or other aspects of the "modern" experience.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is a bug.
See the same issue discussed here:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Search-on-modern-communication-site-url-issue-with-quot-siteall/m-p/205324/highlight/false#M18811